# WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, controller

Please, help to find my mistakes. 
I've got error "WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'"

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Test MVC WEB</display-name>

  <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>o`enter code  here`rg.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<!--     <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file> -->
<!--     <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> -->
<!--     <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file> -->
<!--     <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file> -->
<!--     <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file> -->
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd"
        >




    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <tx:annotation-driven /> 
<!--    <context:component-scan base-package="by.rubanovich" />  -->


    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/config.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

**and controller**

```
package by.rubanovich.controller;

import java.util.Map;

//import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import by.rubanovich.model.Person;
import by.rubanovich.service.PersonService;

@Controller
public class DataController {
//@Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String setupForm(Map<String, Object> map) {
        Person person = new Person();
        map.put("person", person);
        map.put("personList", personService.getAllPersons());
        return "person";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/person.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doAction(@ModelAttribute Person person, BindingResult result,
            @RequestParam String action, Map<String, Object> map) {
        Person personResult = new Person();

        switch (action.toLowerCase()) {

        case "add":
            personService.add(person);
            personResult = person;
            break;
        case "edit":
            personService.edit(person);
            personResult = person;
            break;
        case "delete":
            personService.delete(person.getPersonId());
            personResult = new Person();
        case "search":
            Person searchPerson = personService.getPerson(person.getPersonId());
            personResult = searchPerson != null ? searchPerson : new Person();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        map.put("person", personResult);
        map.put("personList", personService.getAllPersons());
        return "person";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem that the package that contains controllers is not scan by the application.

Uncomment that line in `spring-servlet.xml` :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="by.rubanovich" />
```

**EDIT**

Add this to you `web.xml`

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And correct this listener :

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: thx for answer. but it does't help :( INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization completed in 2566 ms WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TestJavaMvcWeb/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Comment: Have you a unit test that use this URI "/TestJavaMvcWeb" ?

Comment: No. It's just a name of project.. may be i've made wrong structure? [link](http://prntscr.com/2kp5g7)

Answer (score 1):

in my case i have more than one Controller and I got this same problem. After removing a class level request mapping for the controller from where the issue arised solved the problem for me.

Comment: didnt work for me but thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think that you've a problem on your url. Because your controller is configured to manage requests by `@RequestMapping("/index")`

So if your want to access your project `/TestJavaMvcWeb/` you have to:

1. change your `RequestMapping("/index")` to `RequestMapping("/")` or
2. access your `url` by `/TestJavaMvcWeb/index`